# ¿Como dar formato correcto a un string con comillas dobles y comillas simples?

Tags: php, html

Hola tengo el siguiente `String`:

String en PHP:

```
$boton = " <a href='tel:+525550257358' onclick='ga(\'send\', \'event\', \'llamar contacto\', \'llamar3\', \'clic3\');' style='text-decoration:none; color: #666;     font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;'> Teléfono: 5025 7358 </a>";
```

Botón original en HTML

```
<a href='tel:+525550257358' onclick='ga('send', 'event', 'llamar contacto', 'llamar3', 'clic3');' style='text-decoration:none; color: #666;     font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;'> Teléfono: 5025 7358 </a>
```

Les explico: es un botón que contiene un código de Google Analytics, trate de usar esto que le llaman COMILLAS ESCAPADAS y no funciona, en el frontend el botón se muestra pero no me registra el evento de la funcion onclick, justo en donde esta la función ga('send', etc, etc).

Este es el formato con ERROR que me muestra en el front, por el cual no funciona:

```
<a href="tel:+525550257358" onclick="ga(\" send\',="" \'event\',="" \'llamar="" contacto\',="" \'llamar3\',="" \'clic3\');'="" style="text-decoration:none; color: #666;     font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;"> Teléfono: 5025 7358 </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta escapando las comillas dobles asi:

```
$boton = "<a href='tel:+525550257358' onclick=\"ga('send', 'event', 'llamar contacto', 'llamar3', 'clic3');\" style='text-decoration:none; color: #666; font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold;'> Teléfono: 5025 7358 </a>";
```

Comment: Gracias amigo :)